# Ionic Range If true, a pin with integer value is shown when the knob is pressed. can I pin by default show without pressed knob?

Tags: ionic4

If ionic range true, a pin with integer value is shown when the knob is pressed. can I pin by default show without pressed knob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ion-range  #pin mode="md" min="0" max="100" pin="true" knob value="50" ></ion-range>

import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-range',
  templateUrl: './range.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./range.page.scss'],
})
export class RangePage implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  time:any;

  @ViewChild('pin', { static: true}) pin: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    // @ts-ignore
    let child = this.pin.el.shadowRoot.children
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (child.length > 0){
        this.getPin() 
        console.log(child);
        
        clearInterval(timer)
      }
      
    });
  }
  
  getPin(){
   // @ts-ignore
    let children = this.pin.el.shadowRoot.children
    let pinEl = [...children].filter(f => {
      return f.className == 'range-slider'
    })
    let pin = pinEl[0].getElementsByClassName('range-pin')[0]
    pin.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, -24px, 0px) scale(1)'
  }
```